# Openssl key generation on OS X failing

Tags: java, macos, openssl, homebrew

I am attempting to run our unit tests on a new clean mac for a Spring project. One test requires the generation of ssl keys.

I have installed openssl via homebrew but the error continues to persist.

Please see error below:

```
Using configuration from /Users/myuser/workspace/project/webapp/target/test-data/clientvpn/acc1/openssl.conf
default is an unsupported message digest type
13499:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:126:fopen('./index.txt.attr','rb')
13499:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:129:
13499:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:197:
```

Comment: Type `which openssl` and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  `which openssl` printed `/usr/bin/openssl` which is the for the non-homebrew version of openssl. Forcing brew to link the new openssl solved the problem. Please see answer below for a slightly longer description.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have solved the issue with many google searches and consultation with a colleague who has also recently moved to a mac.

The symlinks for the new openssl where not created when homebrew did the installation. If you run `brew link openssl` you will receive the following message `Warning: openssl is keg-only and must be linked with --force`

This leads the the solution. Homebrew needs to be explicitly told to create the correct links.

```
brew link --force openssl
```

If you now check `which openssl` you will notice it points to the brew installed version `/usr/local/bin/openssl`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work any more, even with `--force`.  I get: `Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl`.  It suggests adding it first to `PATH` instead.

Comment: Running the add to path command that brew link gave and restarting terminal worked for me: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: I get this warning: **Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1**

Comment: Not working on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Same warning as above "Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1"

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me on Montery (12.2)

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl # outputs :

Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@3
If you need to have openssl@3 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I was just using the command so I did :

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

That worked, old output :

```
➜  ca git:(master) openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

After:

```
➜  ca git:(master) source ~/.zshrc
➜  ca git:(master) openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021)
```

Note : the other options that may be needed depending on your needs.
Note 2 : my default shell is zsh, add it to your bashrc if you use bash, or to your shell of choice and it's PATH.

Comment: worked for Monterey 12.4 as well, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this flag, worked for me:

```
-CAcreateserial
```

Source:
[Error when signing a CSR using openssl on MacOS](https://joepaulk.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/error-when-signing-a-csr-using-openssl-on-macos/)

Comment: **openssl:Error: '-CAcreateserial' is an invalid command.**

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by allowing my os to access the file.
For ex. macos allow terminal to access this file.